# OpenVPN + iptables - define valid routes

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I have a `bastion` servers which accept users via OpenVPN. The bastion has two network adapters: one leg on the internet and the other leg on a private network. Each user has different IP address and different places where he can visit inside the private network.

For example: the user John has the static IP `10.8.0.1`, on OpenVPN. John can only access this IP address `10.8.1.1`, inside the internal network. Any other place that John will try to access should be blocked.

I tried to do something like this:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --source 10.8.0.1 --destination 10.8.1.1 -j ACCEPT
```

The default policy for INPUT,OUTPUT and FORWARD is block.

I was expected that will allow John access his resource. But actually all his requests are being blocked.

What I'm doing wrong?

### Update 1

Adding the full code:

```
#!/bin/sh
# flush all
iptables -F
iptables -X

# Setting default filter policy
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Allow unlimited traffic on loopback
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --source 10.8.0.1 --destination 10.8.1.1 -j ACCEPT

# make sure nothing comes or goes out of this box
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

Comment: The rest of it seems reasonable. But why do you allow the traffic in only one direction?

Comment: when you want to understand traffic flow, tcpdump or similar is a great tool, run it on one interface, and then on the other and try to understand the flow of traffic and where it "is last seen"

And to debug iptables, creating rules for specific parts, and then check with for example　 `iptables -vnL` to see the counters and if the rule gets hit has helped me several times.

Comment: I've logged the traffic and saw that the opposite direction is my problem (10.8.1.1 -> 10.8.0.1). How to solve it? It should be the same FORWARD command when the `source` and the `destination` is the opposite?